# CKEditor: what's the recommended way of removing all schemes from the HTML?

Tags: url, ckeditor, uri

CKEditor beginner here, so be patient please...

I'm using the CKEditor and I was wondering about the recommended approach for making sure that all the URLs used are absolute without the scheme. For instance, suppose someone inserts an image which points to `http://www.someplace.com/img1.jpg`. I'd like to make sure that the image references only the `//www.someplace.com/img1.jpg`.

Is there any event I should handle or is it better to just do it directly on the source (server side)? Btw, the text isn't limited to a specific number of chars (so it might be just a couple of paragraphs + some pics and anchors or it might be a really long text...)

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert image through Image dialog it should be enough to specify `//path_to_image/image_name.jpg` (without the `http` or `https`). When you insert link through Link dialog, it should be enough to select `Other` in protocol dropdown and specify URL as e.g. `//google.com`. (I think it is also possible to make `Other` the default option in dropdown using [dialogDefinition](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-dialogDefinition) event)

When pasting HTML, text or images you could try using [paste](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-paste) event and modify the incoming data:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', { });
editor.on( 'paste', function( evt ){
    evt.data.dataValue = evt.data.dataValue.replace( /https?\:/, '' );
} );
```